# Ubuntu Java: Find a specific program's pid and kill the program

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, kill, pid

I'm trying to make an application that checks if this specific application is running, then kill the app after a specified amount of time. I'm planning to get the pid of the app. How can I get the pid of the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try `ps -aux | grep foobar` for getting the pid, then issuing the `kill` command against it, alternatively you might want to use [**`pkill`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill)`foobar`, in both cases `foobar` being the name of the app you want to terminate.

Answer (score 5):

pid's for java processes -e.g  `ps -aux | grep java | awk '{print $2}'` .

You can also call `jps` which will give you a process list. A drawback of this is that it will only show you processes for the user issuing the jps command.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `pidof` to get the pid of your application

`pidof  <application name>`

Answer (score 3):

How about this then?

```
public static void killAll(String process) {
    try {
        Vector<String> commands = new Vector<String>();
        commands.add("pidof");
        commands.add(process);
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        Process pr = pb.start();
        pr.waitFor();
        if (pr.exitValue() != 0) return;
        BufferedReader outReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        for (String pid : outReader.readLine().trim().split(" ")) {
            log.info("Killing pid: "+pid);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill " + pid).waitFor();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting this application from script you can get the pid of the last process that was created in background by using the special variable `$!`, this value you can save on a file for later use on your shutdown function.

Below is an example:

```
nohup java -jar example.jar &
echo $! > application.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

`ps aux | awk '/java/ {print "sleep 10; kill "$2}' |  bash`

in Ubuntu, `ps -aux` throws an syntax error, where `ps aux` works.

the output is piped to `awk` which matches lines with java and sleeps for 10seconds and then kills the program with the pId. notice the pipe to bash. Feel free to specify however long you want, or to call what ever other calls you feel appropriate. I notice most of the other answers neglected to catch the 'after a certain amount of time' part of the quesiton.

you could also accomplish this by calling `pidof java | awk '{print "sleep 10; kill "$1}' | bash` but the choice is yours. I generally use ps aux.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to invoke the `ps` and `kill` Unix commands using [Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) and scrape their output. I don't think a Java program can easily inspect / access processes it didn't create.

Answer (score 0):

[Find the pid of a java process under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201589/find-the-pid-of-a-java-process-under-linux)

you can refer to this link...it tell you about finding a pid of specific class name