# kill ubuntu process using PID in java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, pid

I am making some monitoring thread. Have stored the process IDs (PID) in a `hash map`. In thread I am retrieving those PID and on certain condition want to kill particular PID. I searched on web, for `windows` environment the kill command was : `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID "+PID_id);` where PID_id is the PID I get from map. I want to know, how can I do such thing in `ubuntu`(`Linux`) environment.

Comment: You use the `kill` command; read all about it in `man kill`

Comment: Why are you doing that in Java instead of relying on existing OS utilities to handle such stuff?

Comment: check this  > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762257/ubuntu-java-find-a-specific-programs-pid-and-kill-the-program

Answer (score 1):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 "+PID_id);
int retCode = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: if you want return code , the java program has to wait for the proces to complete and do a process.waitFor()

Comment: @sarilsudhakaran what will happen if I don't use `int retCode = process.waitFor();`. I want process with PID_id immediately killed. Don't want to wait for its completion.

Comment: waitFor() is called to make sure that its killed and check the return code . you can ignore that call and continue processing